# Enviar anexo pelo formulário php

Tags: php, html, formulário

Olá, eu tenho um arquivo PHP que envia dados do meu fomulário HTML pelo Email. Só que eu gostaria de enviar anexos também(currículo)pois é uma página de "Trabalhe Conosco". Vi bastante tutoriais por ai, mas eu sempre não consigo entender :( , aqui está o código PHP do formulário atual.

```
 <?php 

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $foto = $_POST['foto'];
    $msg = $_POST['txt'];

    $to ="test@test.com";

    $subject = "Contato - Trabalhe Conosco";

    $body = "Nome: ".$nome."\n".
            "Email: ".$email."\n".
            "Cargo Pretendido: ".$cargo."\n".
            "Cpf: ".$cpf."\n".
            "Foto: ".$foto."\n\n".
            "Mensagem: \n".$msg."\n";

    $header = "From:test@test"."\r\n"."Reply-to:"
               .$email."\r\n";

    if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$header))
    {
        echo "Email enviado com sucesso !";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "O email nПлкo pode ser enviado, tente novamente mais tarde";
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos começar pelo HTML:

No seu `form` você deve inserir o atributo `enctype='multipart/form-data'` para que ele envie o arquivo para seu servidor PHP e o `input` do type file. Assim seu formulário que apenas envia um arquivo ficará assim:

```
 <form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
    <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo"/>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

No PHP parece difícil mas não é, basta lembrar de alguns passos:

1. Recebe arquivo em um local temporário
2. Verifica formato, tamanho e etc... (questão de segurança)
3. Move para o local correto.

   Quando um usuário envia um arquivo para o servidor do PHP, o arquivo fica salvo na variável global $_FILES, semelhante a $_GET e $_POST. Vou postar um codigo já pronto e você confere nos comentários as etapas

PHP

```
    $destino = "uploads/"; // Local onde o arquivo será salvo
    $tamanhoLimite = 15000 // Tamanho maximo do arquivo em bytes
    
    if($_POST['enviar']){
        // Verifica se o  MIME type do arquivo é permitido
        if(strpos($_FILES['arquivo']['type'], "pdf")){ 
            //Move e renomeia o arquivo para o lugar desejado
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $destino.$_FILES['arquivo']['name']);
        }
    }
```

Te recomendo dar uma lida nessa pagina http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php

HTML

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
    <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo"/>
    
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```